# Specify the sdcard application data directory path to logback-android

Tags: android, logback

I am using [logback-android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) in my app for logging. I need to write the log to a file in the application data directory in sdcard. I used below file appender config.

```
<appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/sdcard/Android/data/com.my.app/files/app.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

It can be seen that I have used following log file location.

`/sdcard/Android/data/com.my.app/files/app.log`

I also can use log file location like below.

`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files/app.log`

Above path is the path returned by `getExternalFilesDir()`.

But, the example in the [project wiki page](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/wiki) uses file location in following format.

`/data/data/com.example/files/log/foo.log`.

Above path format does not work in my case, where earlier two path formats I mentioned did work.

What is the correct way to specify the application data directory path in the logback.xml? Can the directory path vary from the first two patterns I mentioned, in various devices?

Comment: use the paths that work . forget about data/data .

Comment: @RobertRowntree, I later realized that `/data/data` path is pointing to the application data directory of the app which is in the protected area of the sdcard (not to the external files directory which is visible to the user). Anyway, my problem is whether the sdcard path pattern remains the same for all devices. I finally decided to set the log file path programatically, so I do not have to worry about hardcoded sdcard file path pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally decided to set the file path programatically. I added following code to the `onCreate()` of my custom `Application` class.

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
for (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger : context.getLoggerList()) {
    for (Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> index = logger.iteratorForAppenders(); index.hasNext(); ) {
        Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = index.next();
        if (appender instanceof FileAppender) {
            ((FileAppender) appender).setFile(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "app.log").getAbsolutePath());
            appender.start();
        }
    }
}
```